# Scrollable layer over another div

Tags: html, css

I have 2 div inside parent. One is text content and another is layer over that text. I am trying to make that layer full of text content.

You can check in example below that blue layer is not full of it's parent.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.any-children {
  width: 700px;
}


.scrollable-wrapper {
    border: solid 1px black;     
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 300px;
    max-width: 500px;
}

.display-content-wrapper {
  position: relative; 
}

.markers-layer {
    color: red;
    border: 3px solid green;
    opacity: 0.7;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
        
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable-wrapper">
    <div class="display-content-wrapper">    
      
    <div class="any-children">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur mollitia maxime facere quae cumque perferendis cum atque quia repellendus rerum eaque quod quibusdam incidunt blanditiis possimus temporibus reiciendis deserunt sequi eveniet necessitatibus maiores quas assumenda voluptate qui odio laboriosam totam repudiandae? Doloremque dignissimos voluptatibus eveniet rem quasi minus ex cumque esse culpa cupiditate cum architecto! Facilis deleniti unde suscipit minima obcaecati vero ea soluta odio cupiditate placeat vitae nesciunt quis alias dolorum nemo sint facere. Deleniti itaque incidunt eligendi qui nemo corporis ducimus beatae consequatur est iusto dolorum consequuntur vero debitis saepe voluptatem impedit sint ea numquam quia voluptate quidem.
    </div>
    
    <div class="markers-layer">
        *
      </div>
    
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/opu1khse/)

Not sure how can i fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `position:absolute` makes element out of flow, you need to use `JS` for it

Answer (score 1):

Please find the code attached below. I have just used `flex(display: flex)` for `(.display-content-wrapper)` class and given **width** and **height**
as `auto` for `(.scrollable-wrapper)` class which would also provide
 responsiveness.

for (.any-children) class.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        * { box-sizing: border-box; }

        .any-children {
        width: 100%;
        }


        .scrollable-wrapper {
        border: solid 1px black;     
        position: relative;
        overflow: auto;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        }

        .display-content-wrapper {
        position: relative; 
        display: flex;
        padding: 10px;
        }

        .markers-layer {
        color: red;
        border: 3px solid green;
        opacity: 0.7;
        background: blue;
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;

        }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="scrollable-wrapper">
        <div class="display-content-wrapper">    
            <div class="any-children">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur mollitia maxime facere quae cumque perferendis cum atque quia repellendus rerum eaque quod quibusdam incidunt blanditiis possimus temporibus reiciendis deserunt sequi eveniet necessitatibus maiores quas assumenda voluptate qui odio laboriosam totam repudiandae? Doloremque dignissimos voluptatibus eveniet rem quasi minus ex cumque esse culpa cupiditate cum architecto! Facilis deleniti unde suscipit minima obcaecati vero ea soluta odio cupiditate placeat vitae nesciunt quis alias dolorum nemo sint facere. Deleniti itaque incidunt eligendi qui nemo corporis ducimus beatae consequatur est iusto dolorum consequuntur vero debitis saepe voluptatem impedit sint ea numquam quia voluptate quidem.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur mollitia maxime facere quae cumque perferendis cum atque quia repellendus rerum eaque quod quibusdam incidunt blanditiis possimus temporibus reiciendis deserunt sequi eveniet necessitatibus maiores quas assumenda voluptate qui odio laboriosam totam repudiandae? Doloremque dignissimos voluptatibus eveniet rem quasi minus ex cumque esse culpa cupiditate cum architecto! Facilis deleniti unde suscipit minima obcaecati vero ea soluta odio cupiditate placeat vitae nesciunt quis alias dolorum nemo sint facere. Deleniti itaque incidunt eligendi qui nemo corporis ducimus beatae consequatur est iusto dolorum consequuntur vero debitis saepe voluptatem impedit sint ea numquam quia voluptate quidem.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="markers-layer">*</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `display: inline-block` (or `inline-flex` / `inline-grid` / `inline-table`) to `.display-content-wrapper` so that it stretches over `.any-children`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

p + p {
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.scrollable-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.display-content-wrapper {
  position: relative; 
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 8px;
}

.any-children {
  width: 150vw;
}

.markers-layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: blue;
  color: red;
  border: 8px solid green;
  opacity: 0.7;
  overflow: hidden;   
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable-wrapper">
  <div class="display-content-wrapper">    
      
    <div class="any-children">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur mollitia maxime facere quae cumque perferendis cum atque quia repellendus rerum eaque quod quibusdam incidunt blanditiis possimus temporibus reiciendis deserunt sequi eveniet necessitatibus maiores quas assumenda voluptate qui odio laboriosam totam repudiandae? Doloremque dignissimos voluptatibus eveniet rem quasi minus ex cumque esse culpa cupiditate cum architecto! Facilis deleniti unde suscipit minima obcaecati vero ea soluta odio cupiditate placeat vitae nesciunt quis alias dolorum nemo sint facere. Deleniti itaque incidunt eligendi qui nemo corporis ducimus beatae consequatur est iusto dolorum consequuntur vero debitis saepe voluptatem impedit sint ea numquam quia voluptate quidem.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur mollitia maxime facere quae cumque perferendis cum atque quia repellendus rerum eaque quod quibusdam incidunt blanditiis possimus temporibus reiciendis deserunt sequi eveniet necessitatibus maiores quas assumenda voluptate qui odio laboriosam totam repudiandae? Doloremque dignissimos voluptatibus eveniet rem quasi minus ex cumque esse culpa cupiditate cum architecto! Facilis deleniti unde suscipit minima obcaecati vero ea soluta odio cupiditate placeat vitae nesciunt quis alias dolorum nemo sint facere. Deleniti itaque incidunt eligendi qui nemo corporis ducimus beatae consequatur est iusto dolorum consequuntur vero debitis saepe voluptatem impedit sint ea numquam quia voluptate quidem.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="markers-layer">*</div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ketan remove the height of any-children

Comment: @TemaniAfif even if i remove height i can't scroll horizontally. I want flexible solution.

Comment: @ketan Check the example above. You can scroll both horizontally and vertically if the content inside `.scrollable-wrapper` is wide or tall enough to make it scrollable.